# How to get calendar days between two dates in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to days between two dates in swift3 by following coding. Unfortunately, I got error and running failed. Please let me know how to solve and how to get calendar days between two dates in swift3.

```
static func getDaysList(_ startDate:String, endDate:String, interval:Int) -> [Date] {
    var dayRange = [Date]()
    let inter = TimeInterval(interval * 60 * 60)
    let ti:TimeInterval = inter
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = datetimeformat
    let dateTo = dateFormatter.date(from: endDate)

    var nextDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startDate)
    let endDate = dateTo!.addingTimeInterval(ti)
    var startTime = NSDate()

    while nextDate!.compare(endDate) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending {
        startTime = nextDate! as NSDate
        dayRange.append(startTime as Date)
        nextDate = nextDate!.addingTimeInterval(ti)
        startTime = nextDate! as NSDate
    }

    return dayRange
}
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

pointed to `let endDate = dateTo!.addingTimeInterval(ti)`

Comment: What does "get calendar days" even _mean?_ What would "good" output be?

Comment: And what errors? On which lines?

Comment: @matt days between two dates.

Comment: I don't know what that means. I know what a date is. But what is a "day" in your mind? I'm serious: show sample input and desired output. I can't imagine what you have in mind here.

Comment: @rmaddy I've edited my question.

Comment: @matt I want to get like `['2016-11-04', '2016-11-05', '2016-11-06', '2016-11-07']` etc

Comment: Those are not dates or days. They are strings.

Comment: @matt I know, I've created `var dates = [Date]()` and want to add those dates into that array.

Comment: It seems to me that the question is well covered by Martin's answer at the duplicate. If not, show why not.

Answer (score -1):

Here

```
 let dateTo = dateFormatter.date(from: endDate)
```

Your `endDate` is likely a string that is not in the correct format for your `dateFormatter`.  Therefore `dateTo` ends up as `nil` and crashes on:

```
let endDate = dateTo!.addingTimeInterval(ti)
```